# How to implement conditional branch in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Pardon me for possibly an easy question.

I want to implement conditional branch like:

```
if need_backprop != 0:
    cross_entropy = ......

if need_backprop == 0:
    tf.stop_gradient(cross_entropy)
```

I find the "if" statement is not valid. So I want to know if there any way to implement conditional branch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **tf.cond:** https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond is what you are looking for.

For an example, your code may be something like this,

```
def case1():
       return cross_entropy = ......

def case2():
       return tf.stop_gradient(cross_entropy)

result = tf.cond(need_backprop != 0, lambda: case1(), lambda: case2())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's really what I want. Thanks a lot.